# How to preserve cursor position on textarea text change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a textarea which automatcally inserts close parens in React, but whenever I modify the textarea's value property, the cursor jumps to the end of the text being edited.

Here's my onChange function:

```
    //on change
    function(event) {

        var newText =  event.target.value

        var cursorPosition = getCursorPosition(event.target)
        if(lastCharacterWasParen(newText, cursorPosition)){
            newText = newText.slice(0, cursorPosition) + ')' + newText.slice(cursorPosition)
        }

        this.setProps({text: newText}})

    }
```

This successfully inserts the paren, but how do I preserve the cursor position?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing similar things before.

The way to change the cursor position is using: `evt.target.selectionEnd`

In your case, you can record down the selectionEnd before inserting, and after inserting, set the selectionEnd to the position it should be.

Comment: `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are definitely way to go, but you have to be sure there are no custom selection in textarea.

Comment: @borisano yup, you are right, I just think of it. If there is nothing should be selected after the operation, set selectionStart=selectionEnd. If you want to select anything surrounded by the paren, change accordingly. And also, no sure what will happen if selectionStart > selectionEnd...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectionStart` prop as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745867/how-do-you-get-the-cursor-position-in-a-textarea) to store and then reset cursor position

```
var cursorPosition = $('#myTextarea').prop("selectionStart");
```

Then use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) to set cursor position