# can anyone explain, how to get cursor position in textarea in safari?

Tags: safari, textarea

> hi team, I am facing problem  in desktop safari while writing
>   something in textarea. i want to know how to get the caret position in
>   text area.  i searched a lot but didn't find anything suitable  kindly
>   help me.
>
> thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the cursor position in a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745867/how-do-you-get-the-cursor-position-in-a-textarea)