# Insert text at cursor position niceEdit

Tags: rich-text-editor, nicedit

I'm using [NiceEdit](http://nicedit.com/) for a project.
How to insert text at current cursor position?

The `getContent()` function reqturns whole text. If I add something like `getContent()+someText` someText always appear after getContent().

How to insert text in current cursor position?

Comment: The standard way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745867/how-do-you-get-the-cursor-position-in-a-textarea - combining the javascript with a library like jquery might help a bit.

Comment: Pls give some details. jQuery can't read content on niceEdit textarea content.