# How to correctly grab and replace selected text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, position, character, selection

Here is code:

```
var selection;
var edited_selection;
var value;
var string;

    $("#text").select(function(){ // $("#text") is textarea
       value = $("#text").val(); 
       selection = window.getSelection();   
       string = selection.toString();     
    });

    $("#bold").click(function(){
       edited_selection = "<b>" + string + "</b>"; 
       var replacing = value.replace(string, edited_selection);
       $("#text").val(replacing);
    });
```

When I  click on some common number or character, it will wrap the first occurence of that character or number. For example easy sentence: "Hello there". If I will try to select the last "e" from that sentence, it will select the first occurence of "e" and it will wrap like **e**, but i wanted to select the last "e". How can I do it? Thank you for answers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: When I click on #bold element I want to wrap selected text in <b> </b> tag.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-caret-position-within-an-text-input-field