# prevent div scroll when using cursor keys in input or text area - safari/chrome

Tags: jquery, forms, webkit, keyboard

http://jsfiddle.net/ianhk/t9Hj6/

```
<div style="width:250px; height: 100px; border: black solid 1px; overflow:auto">
  <table style="height:200px; border: red solid 1px">
    <tr>
      <td>abcdefghi</td>
      <td>
        <input id="text" value="Some text">
      </td>
      <td>abcdefghi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

$("#text").on("keydown", function (ev) {
   ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

In the fiddle above I have a div with overflow set to auto, containing an oversized table with an input form element in one of the cells.

With safari and chrome using left/right cursor keys causes the div to scroll left/right when the left-most/right-most position is reached. I want to avoid the div scroll.

Things I've tried:

- keydown/preventDefault - prevents the cursor keys working (obviously)
- keydown/stopPropagation - no change, was expecting this to stop the event bubbling to the div
- wrapping the input in a form and trying to stopPropagation on that
- disable scrolling on the div whilst editing - this gets complex when IE/FF hide/show scrollbars and contents move around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a rig but you could detect the position of the caret in relation to the text length using for instance this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897510 then you could simply return false if at the end (or start) of text and attempting to move.

Comment: thanks - not elegant as you hint, but fixes left/right. Still left with a lesser problem for para start/end and page up/down which don't behave the same way (on a mac). IE/FF-mac do the sensible thing and don't bubble up the keys.