# cursor is jumping when pressing the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox, where a forbidden character cant be typed. #.

This works, however, when the textbox is filled in with data, and I put the focus on the middle of the textbox and then I use the arrow keys to go left and right, then it jumps to the end of the textbox.

If I type a character also in the middle of the textbox, it goes to the end again

```
$('[id$=txtClient]').keyup(function () {
        EnableClientValidateButton(); // When the textbox changes, the user has the ability to validate the client
        ChangeColorClient("0"); // The color is changed to white, to notify the user the client is not validated yet.
        var $el = $('[id$=txtClient]'); // the text element to seach for forbidden characters.
        var text = $el.val(); // The value of the textbox
        text = text.split("#").join("");//remove occurances of forbidden characters, in this case #
        $el.val(text);//set it back on the element
    });
```

Comment: The way you are stopping them enter # is wrong.  You should just check on keyup and not allow the # key there.

Comment: Was just making you a demo but Christoph got there first :)

Comment: It does now, and is better than my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit unpleasant, and I'm not 100% happy, but it solves all the given issues that you've had...

```
$("[id$=txtClient]").keyup(function (e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if (text.indexOf("#") > -1) {
        text = text.replace("#", "");
        $(this).val(text);
    }
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle example...

http://jsfiddle.net/E4cBK/

Answer (score 3):

Javascript allows you to set the cursor position for inputs.

I found two useful functions:

- getCaretPosition - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897229/2335291
- setCaretPosition - https://stackoverflow.com/a/512542/2335291

And the solution could look like this:

```
  function getCaretPosition (elem) {

    // Initialize
    var iCaretPos = 0;

    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {

      // Set focus on the element
      elem.focus ();

      // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
      var oSel = document.selection.createRange ();

      // Move selection start to 0 position
      oSel.moveStart ('character', -elem.value.length);

      // The caret position is selection length
      iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0')
      iCaretPos = elem.selectionStart;

    // Return results
    return (iCaretPos);
  }

  function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
      if(elem != null) {
          if(elem.createTextRange) {
              var range = elem.createTextRange();
              range.move('character', caretPos);
              range.select();
          }
          else {
              if(elem.selectionStart) {
                  elem.focus();
                  elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
              }
              else
                  elem.focus();
          }
      }
  }

$('[id$=txtClient]').keyup(function () {
    EnableClientValidateButton(); // When the textbox changes, the user has the ability to validate the client
    ChangeColorClient("0"); // The color is changed to white, to notify the user the client is not validated yet.
    var $el = $('[id$=txtClient]'); // the text element to seach for forbidden characters.
    var text = $el.val(); // The value of the textbox
    text = text.split("#").join("");//remove occurances of forbidden characters, in this case #

    var pos = getCaretPosition(this);
    $el.val(text);//set it back on the element
    setCaretPosition(this, pos);
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU! (NB: Works in Chrome and Opera as well)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `keypress` event ?

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) warns about possible differences in behavior between platforms.

In Firefox at least, `e.which` corresponds to the ascii code of the typed character after transformation :

```
$('#txtClient').keypress(function (e) {
    console.log('keypress:', e.which);
    if (e.which == 35) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebcet/12/)

Comment: unfortunately the cursor is still jumping when trying to insert the `#` in the middle. I guess you cannot solve this easily as claustrophobs proposed answer is good, but the CaretPosition is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent to execute your code if the user presses a right or a left arrow.
To do this you just need to add this condition:

```
if(e.which != 37 && e.which != 39){
```

You can find the key codes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Your full code would be:

```
$('[id$=txtClient]').keyup(function () {
    if(e.which != 37 && e.which != 39){  
        EnableClientValidateButton();
        ChangeColorClient("0"); 
        var $el = $('[id$=txtClient]'); 
        var text = $el.val(); 
        text = text.split("#").join("");
        $el.val(text);//set it back on the element
    }
});
```

[LIVING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ebcet/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just prevent the keypress for #?  With your example you've not resolved the issue of typing in the middle of the textbox.

Comment: @Archer You are right. I forgot about that part... I will take another look.

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent the default action on **keypress**(keydown does not give consistent charCodes):

```
$('[id$=txtClient]').keypress(function (e) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '#'){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

This just prevents `#` and leaves the rest as it is.

[Here you go;)](http://jsfiddle.net/ebcet/10/)

Comment: Tried the demo? Which browser?

Comment: I've changed the character code for you - should have been 222

Comment: Still not working in any of my browsers (IE 9, Chrome 27, Firefox...)

Comment: @Steve Because Archer changed it wrong. Several special keys unfortunately have different keycodes in different browsers

Comment: @LuisValencia apparently `#` is a character where the keycode is dependent on the OS/Browser/Font whatever. KeyCodes 191 and 163 work for me in all browsers.

Comment: @Christoph Sorry - my bad.  I assumed it was a standard ASCII code.  That's my new thing learnt for the day :)  222 works find for me in Chrome.  There must be a way of narrowing it down.

Comment: then I need another solution. :(

Comment: @LuisValencia try my revised version! ;)

Comment: @Christoph - Much better than the ham-fisted way I suggested.  I wasn't aware of `String.fromCharCode()`

Comment: @Archer This only works with keypress though, which yields consistent results because in this state of the key event, it is mapped to the actual symbol and not the key on the keyboard. The only unpleasent thing is that keypress is not part of the official standard, that's why I tried to avoid it in the first place. [See my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188302/consistent-keycode-for) :-D