# consistent keyCode for `#`

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

While I know that capturing keys due to the `e.keyCode` vs `e.charCode` is not trivial, I thought that jQuery would pretty much be able to normalize most of those inconsistencies.

However while [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187324/1047823) I found out that the character `#` seems to have very inconsistent keyCodes (and of course  this is true for several other codes also, mostly depending on the browser and keyboardlayout I guess).

Chrome and IE yielded 191, Firefox 163 on my computer, another user reported 222. Chromes `window.event` even reported `U+00BF` as keyIdentifier - which according to unicode tables should be `¿`.

Do you know any consistent way to determine such symbols like the `#` with inconsistent keyCodes without doing something nasty like the following:

```
$('input').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 191 || e.which == 163 || e.which == 222){
            // hope you got the right key
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

[Fiddle for your pleasure.](http://jsfiddle.net/ebcet/8/)

Comment: Uhm... `#` is a key `3` with `shift` modifier. There is no key `#` at all

Comment: @zerkms I guess that depends on your keyboard layout:-p

Comment: still - it's **key**down. There is no key `#`

Comment: In the fiddle I get 16 when I press the shift key and 51 when I press the 3 key.

Comment: @zerkms I don't know what you are talking about. A key is a part of the keyboard, and mine is equipped with a key holding a `#` symbol. Perhaps you should get a proper keyboard? But enough smack talk, every userinput generates a keycode, so `#` will too. The question is how to *reliably* detect that.

Comment: Keycodes from `keyup/down` represent a key on a keyboard, not a character. This code doesn't depend on used language, rather it depends on the manufacturer of the keyboard/JS implementation. You can get a _character_ code when using `onkeypress`.

Comment: @Teemu keypress is not part of the official standard, that's why I tried to avoid it.

Comment: I see... Though I've always used it when characters have been needed, without any troubles. Btw, it seems I've (scandinavian) a similar keyboard with zerkms, for example `[` appears by hitting `AltGr + 8`.

Comment: @Christoph @zerkms Keyboards differ around the world, and between manufacturers. The keyboard I'm typing this on has a `#` key, next to enter (http://www.trusted-pc-components.co.uk/images/fujitsu-siemens-amilo-m7440-uk-keyboard.jpg). My MacBook Air's keyboard doesn't (http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Apple-MacBook-Air-11-6-inch-2012-review-keyboard-display.jpg). (On the Mac, `#` is 3 with an alt modifier, rather than shift.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me in Chrome and Firefox with a US keyboard:

```
$('[id$=txtClient]').keypress(function (e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '#') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

`keypress` is the only event that will give you reliable info on the *character* that was entered.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/ebcet/9/

Comment: I read about keypress being unreliable, that's why I tried to avoid this: `as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.` But it works for me, too. Also that `String.fromCharCode` is really neat!

Comment: I'm not sure if jQuery does some magic to the `keypress` event but has always worked for me in IE8+ and all modern browsers.

Comment: I'll wait for another answer that perhaps can achieve the same without keypress, otherwise of course I will accept your's as I'm delighted by the fromCharCode;).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `keypress` event ?

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) warns about possible differences in behavior between platforms.

In Firefox at least, `e.which` corresponds to the ascii code of the typed character after transformation :

```
$('#txtClient').keypress(function (e) {
    console.log('keypress:', e.which);
    if (e.which == 35) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebcet/12/)

Comment: 10 minutes too late dude:-p