# How to get text from contenteditable div from beginning to the cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor-position

Is there a way to get text from `contenteditable div` from beginning to *cursor position*.
For example:

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
</div>
```

Assumption 1: cursor blinking after the word *quick*. The query to the function must return *the quick*

Assumption 2: *cursor blinking* at the end of the sentence. The query to the function must return *the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.*

Comment: may be this could help you:`--->` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613431/jquery-get-the-cursor-position-after-click

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
getTextFromHeadToCaret: function () {
            var element = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
            var caretOffset = 0;
            if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
                var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
                preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
                preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
                caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
                var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
                var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
                preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
                caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
            }
            var divStr = $('#editableDiv').text();
            return divStr.substring(0, caretOffset);
        }
```

Comment: How to get from the cursor position to the end ?

Comment: Got it;
`var divStr = $('#editableDiv').text();
  return divStr.substring(caretOffset, divStr.length);`