# how to get the character based on the position of the cusor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to determine the last character of a string in a text input field, but ignoring any characters to the right of the cursor. Essentially I want to determine the the character directly left of the cursor. So far I can only get characters based on there position within the string like this:

```
var str = $('#tBox').val();
var lastChar = str.charAt(str.length-1 );

<input type = "text" id = "tBox">
```

is what I'm asking possible? Thank you.

Comment: try the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-within-an-text-input-field  then use substr

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was helpful, I will take some time to study the answers