# MVC format number EU style for both server and client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm searching for days how to format my both double and double? **inputs** as 
**decimal = comma and thousand separator =dot**

example:

> 123456.01 ==> 123.456,01
>
> 14,02 ==> 14,02
>
> 987654321,002 ==> 987.654.321,002

what i did so far:

1. I checked server/local region setting
2. add globalization in my web.config

   **globalization uiCulture="fr-BE" culture="fr-BE**
3. In my model i used the following attribute (but i'm using TextBoxFor)

   ```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N3}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   ```

   @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.size, new {tabindex=11, id = "SizTotText", @class = "form-control input-sm calc" })

but
How can I:

1- while user is typing, the number should be formatted ?
I found this solution: [how to format input box text as I am typing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470499/how-to-format-input-box-text-as-i-am-typing-it)
but i cannot switch comma with Dot [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcz4a2ca/10/)

2- Created Custom helper following this post (changed decimal to double)[Post](http://mvc%20custom%20html%20decimal%20format)

there are a lot of solution in stackoverflow but none seems to work for me.

I hope my question is clear and sorry for my bad english

**EDIT:**

I decided to ignore the client formatting, no more dot's and comma but i still have issue with the regional setting.

My application still treating the dot as decimal separator, how can i fix this?
and more funny, it accepts some fields and others not, although they all have the same attribute, settings ... etc see screen shot
[image: error message]
[image: Fields]

The field that has an error is a calculated field

```
   var url = '@Url.Action("CalculateDropPrec", "Drop")';
    $('.calc').change(function () {
        // get the values of the textboxes
        var numUsed = $('#numUseText').val();
        var totNumUsed = $('#totNumUseText').val();
        $.post(url, { nUsed: numUsed, tUsed: totNumUsed }, function (response) {
            $('#precText').val(response);
        });
        return false;
    });


@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PerceDropTot, new {data_val = "false", id = "precText", name = "precText", @class = "form-control input-sm drop-read", placeholder = "0.0", @readonly = "readonly" })


public JsonResult CalculateDropPrec(double nUsed, double tUsed)
{
    var result = CommonComputation.CalcPrecDrop(nUsed, tUsed);
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Adding the thousands separator in the textbox means you could not bind to your model without also creating a custom model binder that converts your string back to a `decimal` (a `decimal` type cannot be bound to a value containing thousands separators). You might consider [this project](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-numericinput) as an alternative

Comment: Rather than setting `$('#precText').val(response);` you could try to first format the result to a number of you expected format and precision, doing something like this: `$('#precText').val(parseFloat(response).toFixed(3));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not going into the direction you want, but is "number formatting as you type" really desired? the downside is that the behaviour can become very tricky, and I mean also for the user. Assume that you type the number "`1234`" which becomes "`1.234`". When the input field is focused again and the caret is placed here: "`1.|234`", is it clear what happens when Backspace is hit? Is the point removed, or the `1`? What happens when the user tries to type `,` or `.` manually? All the questions need to be considered. Also, when you POST the value in a FORM, it's not a valid numeric when formatted.

For those reason, even advanced Controls with Numeric Inputs like the [Kendo UI NumericTextBox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index) which we use heavily, choose to format a display-only value but not intercept user inputs (try the linked Demo).

But you can also check how [cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) solves the issue, it does the realtime formatting, but probably uses the browsers culture settings. But personally don't like [how it behaves](https://jsfiddle.net/nosir/aLnhdf3z/) when trying to correct already existing values.

Comment: Thankx for taking the time to answer my question, I decided to ignore the formatting part however randomly some fields are not treated as numeric please see my update