# Removing toLocaleString formating when checking field validation

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form field (string) for which I'm adding a "space" thousand separator using this script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470499/how-to-format-input-box-text-as-i-am-typing-it
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#input_10").on('keyup', function(){
        var n = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
        $(this).val(n.toLocaleString());
        });
    </script>
```

So user types : "100000" and it will display "100 000"

Later on, during form submission, I have a PHP statement which verifies if the field contains a numeric value.

Now comes the problem ($value is the value of the formatted field):

1. is_numeric($value) is not true due to the "space" thousand separator, so I tried removing the space but:
2. is_numeric(str_replace(' ', '', $value)) is also not true and does not delete the space added by toLocaleString

**How can delete the toLocaleString format that has been added in jQuery when doing my field validation in PHP?**

**EDIT:** PHP Code used:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_1_10', 'bja_gf_custom_validation10', 10, 4 );
function bja_gf_custom_validation10( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $formatedNumber = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        if ( $result['is_valid'] && !is_numeric($formatedNumber) ) {
            $result['is_valid'] = false;
            $result['message'] = 'formatedNumber:' . $formatedNumber;
        }
        return $result;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: `is_numeric(str_replace(" ","","100 000"));` is `true`. Show us your PHP code.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the toLocaleString probably added a char that is **not** an empty space.

If I enter "100000" (which renders as "100 000") and then do a PHP:

`ord(substr($value,4,1));`

I receive the ascii code 160...

Comment: Maybe take a look at removing ASCII Chars from PHP String: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176923/715105

Answer (score 1):

ASCII Code 160 = Non-Breaking Space.

Try using this regex to catch any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

```
$re = '/\p{Z}/'; // (any kind of whitespace or invisible separator)
$str = '100 000'; // Your form input    
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);    
// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Once you have your matches/results, you could remove them from your variable(s).

Test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/sdHYmw/1

If it is just the non-breaking space that you want to remove, and your page is encoded with UTF-8, in which case the encoding for a non-breaking space is 0xC2 0xA0...you could also try this:

```
$YourFormInput = trim($YourFormInput, "\xC2\xA0");
```

Comment: Humm it didn't catch anything. I've even tried replacing directly the chr(160) using this:

`$formatedNumber = str_replace(chr(160), "", $value);`

But then I end up with the question mark in a diamond char instead of the char 160.

Comment: Maybe take a look at removing ASCII Chars from PHP String: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176923/715105

Answer (score 0):

You have juste to use: 
preg_replace("/[^\d]+/","",$my_var);