# How do you format a field as you type for currency but support backspace and edits?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I love this function below, it works perfectly for formatting US dollars as you type, however, I have not been able to figure out an issue with cursor re-positioning as it relates to using the backspace or highlighting and replacing more then one number at a time. For example, if you run the code snipped try to replace the "32" in the number with "89" using backspace or highlighting it and typing over it.

Is there a way to support this? Maybe with cursor repositioning?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on('click keyup paste', 'input.dollar:not([readonly])', function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8) {
      var par = $(this).parents('.listingbox');
      // skip for arrow keys
      if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) return;
      // format number

      $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        var $ret = value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return '$' + $ret;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="dollar" value="$342,323,123" />
```

Comment: If you've copied that function from somewhere, it would be a good idea to give credit.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279790/215552) to the similar question [how to format input box text as I am typing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19470499/215552).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing one for your own usage.
Some things to keep in mind:

- Should take only numbers
- $ symbol should be present only in the beginning
- Commas should pop up as we enter the number(every 3 digit starting from the right)
- Not sure if decimals are allowed

Keeping this in mind, we can write a `onchange` trigger on the input element.

Let me know what else anyone else have in mind.