# Get Cursor Position With Input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the position of the cursor in an `<input>`. Here is the code that I am using:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    $("<p>")
    .html("Cursor position at " + $("input").caretPosition())
    .appendTo("#test");
});
```

And `caretPosition` is defined as (just a wrapper for `selectionStart`):

```
$.fn.caretPosition = function() {
    if (!this.length) return;
    var input = this[0];
    try {
      return input.selectionStart;
    } catch(e) {
      // No need for old IE support
      return 0;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" />
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Unfortunately this isn't working in chrome, but it is working if Firefox. In chrome, it prints `0` all the time. This would make me think that chrome doesn't support `selectionStart` but I have read that it does support `selectionStart`. This is supported by the fact that if I change `type="number"` to `type="text"` it starts working. How do I get it to work consistently across browsers for `type="number"`? (not IE, don't need support for that).

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897510/3371119 but it doesn't work for me (in chrome).

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/zbaaky5z/2/

**Edit**: I have confirmed that `selectionStart in input` returns true. So why is an error thrown?

Comment: Only a few input types support selectionStart according to the standard. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#input-type-attr-summary  Why do you want to get the caret position?

Comment: @int32_t Good point. Thanks. I just realized that when I checked the console error message if I remove the `try {} catch` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @int32_t pointed out, this is impossible with `<input type="number" />`. I changed it to `<input type="text" />` and was able to receive this functionality; I added my own number-validating method like so:

```
function validate(k) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(k)) && !isNaN(+k);
}
```

In fact, if you remove the `try {} catch {}` statements, chrome throws a very descriptive error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionStart' property from
'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support
selection.
```