# Intercept an ngModel binding with an Angular Directive

Tags: angular, binding, interceptor, ngmodel

I ask myself if it possible to intercept an ngModel binding with an Angular directive.

For example:

template:

```
<input type="string" [(ngModel)]="numberVal" name="someName" appNumberInput>
```

component:

```
public numberVal: number;
```

directive:

```
selector: '[appNumberInput]'
// magic happens to convert a number to string and vice versa.
```

This problems comes up because it is not possible to use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` with `<input type="number>" ([Get Cursor Position With Input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25353585) and [selectionStart/selectionEnd on input type="number" no longer allowed in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21177489)).

I know, I could create a custom component which wraps a native input component.
However, I wonder if this is solvable with only a custom directive.

I tried two directive prototypes:

1. Implement NgValueAccessor:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumberInput]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumberInputDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class NumberInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {}

  private onChange: (_: any) => void = () => {};

  private onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = value != null ? value : '';
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  onInput(value: string): void {
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
    this.onChange(isNaN(parsedValue) ? null : parsedValue);
  }

}
```

2. Provide ngModel in the constructor:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomNgModelInterceptor]',
  providers: [NgModel],
})
export class CustomNgModelInterceptorDirective {
  constructor(private ngModel: NgModel) {
    ngModel.valueChanges.pipe(tap((value) => {
      console.log('changed value', value); // this line is never triggered. 
    }));
  }
}
```

I would expect that the `numberVal` would be transformed to a string for input bindung but parsed back as float for the output binding.

None of these versions will update the bounded value.