# Capture down array press before cursor is moved

Tags: javascript, dom-events, autosuggest, keyup

If the cursor is positioned somewhere in an input box, is there some way to capture that position using `keyup` before Firefox moves the cursor to the end of the box?

I'm making a dropdown of suggestions for each input box and I only want the suggestions to be moved into if the cursor was already at the end of the input box. However, when I try to capture the cursor position to test this, it always returns the end, since the cursor moves to the end before my event handler starts.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution but it involves a global variable, which seems messy for a little thing like this. I declare a variable

```
// global scope
var lastCursorPosition;
```

Then I have a `keydown` event handler on the inputBox

```
inputBox.onkeydown = function(event) { 
    if(event.keyCode === 40) { 
        lastCursorPosition = cursorPosition(inputBox); 
    }
};
```

Finally, in the `keyup` event (which has other things in it), I do

```
inputBox.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 40 && lastCursorPosition >= inputBox.value.length - 1) {
        // show suggestions
    }
};
```

If anyone has a more modular solution, I'd be glad to hear it.

BTW: If anyone's curious, I'm using the `cursorPosition` function given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897229/2407870).