# getting caret position with spaces in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem is with spaces. Sometimes if the caret is on a space, it ignores the space and finds the position of the last character (that isn't a space). In this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tekjedow/)** if you click just right of the letter c it shows caret position as 3. Then click just left of the letter d (one character along) and it still shows caret position as 3. However if you click left of d first, then it shows position 4 (the correct position). If anyone can take a look at my jsFiddle and try this out maybe you can find a solution. Thank you.

NB this code only works in IE.

```
$('input').click(function(){
  var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
      Sel.moveStart('character', -this.value.length);
      CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
  $('span').text(CaretPos);
```

});

Comment: this code doesnt work for me in the latest ie, chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The `selectionStart` [worked](http://jsfiddle.net/tekjedow/13/) in latest IE, Firefox & Chrome.

```
$('input').click(function(){
    this.focus();
     /**var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
     Sel.moveStart('character', -inelem.value.length);
     CaretPos = Sel.text.length;*/
    CaretPos = this.selectionStart;   
    $('span').text(CaretPos);
});
```

But, if you are concerned about supporting older IE versions, you can conditionally invoke `createRange` over `selectionStart`. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tekjedow/11/) version of fiddle. The `doGetCaretPosition` is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field) link