# jquery how append text to text area while typing

Tags: jquery

I need to add a static text to textarea while typing.

```
var text= " my text";
$("#myInput").keydown(function() {
    $("#myInput").val(this.value + text);
});
```

The above code adds " my text" to textarea, and after that if I continue typing, it starts to type after "text" word. I need my cursor stay always before " my text".

Comment: you can use this technique to set the cursor to the cursorpostino you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Answer (score 2):

You need a function to get the cursor position:

[Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

And a function to set the cursor position:

[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)

Then you can do what you want:

```
var text= "my text";
var textIsSet = false;
$("#myInput").keydown(function() {
    var cpos = doGetCaretPosition(this);
    if(!textIsSet) {
        $(this).val(this.value + text);
        textIsSet = true;
    }
    setCaretToPos(this, cpos);
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b69v5fvs/

Comment: It works, but I do with 2 lines of CSS what you do with 60 lines of javascript. And my answer got downvoted.

Comment: You have a clever solution, but not for the OPs problem. The task is to work with a textarea. To use your contenteditable  tag in a form would require more javascript.

Comment: I agree with that. But if by chance, they can work with something else than a textarea, I provided an alternative solution that would be lighter. If they can't, well your answer works best =) So +1 to you too.

Answer (score 1):

With an input field or a textarea, it's dirty and doesn't work well (especially when deleting...)

```js
var text= " my text";
$("#myInput").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(this.value.replace(text,"") + text);
});
```

```css
input{
    width : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput"/>
```

I would rather use a `contenteditable` element, with an `:after` in pure CSS :

```css
p{
    min-width : 300px;
    border: grey solid 1px;
}
p:after{
    content:" my text"
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable></p>
```

Comment: _I need my cursor stay always before " my text"._ is it mentioning it?

Comment: That's the case. Try it.

Comment: does not seem to be i can see the cursor at the end every time i type.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. Anyway, the result is correct, even if the cursor isn't _visually_ at the right character in FF or other browser : `whatever you type + my text`. It can't be otherwise with an `:after`. Did you correct your non-working answer? :)

Comment: No need to get angry. Your solution works perfectly for me. +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks Mario! I get angry because people on SO have an habit to downvote without reason. Good answers get downvoted without any comment, sometimes even after the OP says "Thanks it worked". And that gets on my nerves.