# Get cursor axis of a textfield in javascript on keyup event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get cursor (blinking cursor) axis of a text-field on keyup event. I researched a lot but did not get any solution.

There are methods in MouseEvent i.e clientX and clientY. Is it possible get axis of the blinking cursor on KeyUp?

Here is the HTML :

```
<input type="password" ng-model="password" onkeyup="dirty()">
```

Here is my script :

```
function dirty(){//get the cursor axis here}
```

Comment: :) Add in Jsfiddle Buddy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

Comment: I asked for cursor AXIS, not cursor position

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK not. You can get all the info of mouse event only when mouse event occurred. When it is a keyboard event you can't