# How to split the value of a textarea with the cursor position as the last line

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I want to split the value of a textarea with `\n` and make the line where the cursor is positioned as the last value in the array for example:

```
1. fyg tgiyu rctvyu cuiby cutv cutrvyb crtvyb
2. rutyu rtcvyb ctrvybu ctrvybu rtcvy
3. rutiyu crtvyu crtvyb rtvyb
4. |
5. tgyho8uji vtybui
6. tvybui yivtubi
```

Now the numbers are the lines in the textarea and line 4 is the line where the cursor is positioned. so I want to split the lines ignoring line 5 and 6 have line 4 as the last line. Then I will run a code like this:

```
lastLine = //the position of the cursor
if(lastLine == ""){
    console.log('empty');
} else {
    //get the value of the previous line before the lastLine
}
```

Please how do I achieve this using jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: What have  you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by the `jQuery` `substr()`.

You select the substring of the textarea value from the starting point to the point where the cursor is located and split it with line breaks. Like this;

```
value = $('textarea').val();
// to get the position of the cursor
index = $('textarea').prop('selectionstart');
// select all from the starting point to the cursor position ignoring line 5 and 6
str = value.substr(0, index);
// split the str with a line break
splt = str.split('\n');
// then finally to get your last line
lastLine = splt[splt.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#theTextArea').prop("selectionStart");` 
and

`$('#theTextArea').prop("selectionEnd");`

The above properties give you the location of the cursor on modern browsers.  This question has been [linked here before though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field).  For older browsers it could be problematic.

But given the cursor position you should be able to just grab the substring to the cursor index.  Then use a regex to get the contents of the last line to the end of the string.