# Get text which is after cursor in contenteditable

Tags: jquery

I have been searching for this so long, but no result.

What I'm looking for is: At first, just one `li`( which has child `contenteditable`) appears, after pressing `enter`, it adds adds another `li`, like here in my fiddle: [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2xfo5w4/11/).

Here everything works fine, but this case should be just when cursor is in the end or start of the sentence. For example, if cursor is in the middle, I want that, when pressing `enter`, to get the text which is after cursor.

Can I do that?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can [get the cursor position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field) and then slice the text. By the way, you have great family name :)

Comment: ahhah, thnx :P, but how can I slice the text? @Vohuman