# What is the reliable way to get cursor position after text inserted?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, the event order is like this:

1. keydown
2. keypress
3. change
4. keyup

I get the current cursor position with this:

```
function getCursorPosition(event) {
  var lines = event.target.value.slice(0, event.target.selectionStart)
  return {
    row: lines.length,
    col: lines[lines.length - 1].length
  }
}
```

If I put the function in `onkeydown` or `onkeypress` event, the return value
is the cursor position before text inserted

If I put the function in `onchange` event, the function is not called when I hit
`arrow` key or other key that triggers cursor movement.

If I put the function in `onkeyup` event, the function is not called when I don't
release key (holding keydown).

Now, the only way I can think of is to put the function in both `onchange` and
`onkeyup`. Flag `change` event in `onchange`. Calls the function only if `change`
flag is not true on `keyup`. And set `change` flag on keyup to false.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov the answer there will give different return value on `keydown` and `change` event. I want to track down the cursor position on every keydown, but I need the return value from `keyup` or `change` event.

Comment: The `event` object for events that you're using doesn't return current position, also, besides of left/right keys, Ctrl(Command)/Alt jumps there is also mouse pointing so the best option will be to query every time for target element.

Comment: _“the function is not called when I don't release key (holding keydown)”_ – and why/how is that a problem? Doing anything with the “current” cursor position while the user is still pressing arrow keys doesn’t seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: @CBroe I need to draw cursor somewhere else with the exact same position with the current cursor position even when I holding the key down. So, If I hold left key, the cursor should run to the left too in that place, but with the position after text inseted. It's text editor with hidden textarea. Like codemirror

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov That's my question, that `every time`. Is it every `keydown`, every `keypress`, every `change` or every `keyup`? And yes, I mean `event.target` there. I forgot it, sorry. It's typo.