# Get cursor position in input - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Like [get cursor position in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field), I want to get the mouse cursor position in text using  `ng-keydown` function:

So if the user wants to delete the x `char` in `String` I will get `x`.

```
<input 
     name="inputText" 
     type="text" 
     ng-keypress="changeInput($event)"
     ng-keydown="backSpace($event)"
 >
```

controller:

```
vm.changeInput = function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //get cusor position in input text
   //some more logic goes here

};
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get the selected text which was selected via the mouse cursor?

Comment: No, only the position(x in string).

Comment: Are you trying to get the resultant change after they alter the string? If so, why not just use `ng-change` and return the resultant string? You can then do a comparison of the string from before the change and after to get your changed value.

Comment: No, I just want the current char position the cusor is on or before.

Comment: Again read the question - input and not Textarea.

Comment: Refer here http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/02/get-cursor-position-in-text-input-field.html#.WKRuxWXRuqA