# Word under cursor in hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it real to get a word under cursor in `textarea/input` using `hover/mousemove` event?

Or at least get caret position?

Comment: do you need cursor or caret?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)