# How to update the state in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, state

Initially I had a CKeditor component, from where I had a state variable editorContent

```
 <CKEditor id="currentCKEditor" activeClass="editor" key={this.state.editorContent} content={this.state.editorContent} events={{ "change": this.onChange, "instanceReady": this.ckeditorInstanceReady }} />
```

When component is rendered, the editorContent comes from the templatestoreChange.
[image: EditorContent state has the following data]

```
_templateStoreChange(type) {

    if (type == 'SingleTemplate') {
        let singletemplate = TemplateStore._getSingleTemplate() || {};
        console.log("single template response", singletemplate);
        this.setState({ editorContent: singletemplate.template.html });
    }
}
```

After templateStoreChange logSig is called here the editorContent changes.
[image: Instead of editorContent State getting updated It is previous state is getting removed and changing the entire editorContent.]

```
  logSig = () => {
   const signaturedata = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();

    let elem= '<img alt src=' + signaturedata + ' />';
    this.setState({
        openSignatureDialog: false,
        editorContent:elem
    })
    console.log("signaturedata", signaturedata);

}`enter code here`
```

I need the state to get updated instead of entire state being removed and changed to a new state.

Comment: please anyone provide me quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned only `elem` variable to `editorContent` and losing whole content created before.

The solution is to concatenate `elem` variable to existing state.

```
logSig = () => {
    const signaturedata = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();

    let elem = '<img alt src=' + signaturedata + ' />';
    this.setState({
        openSignatureDialog: false,
        editorContent: this.state.editorContent + elem
    })
}
```

Comment: By inserting this.state.editorContent + elem like this the elem is populating after this.state.editorContent
Instead of after i am using editor where ever cursor place i need to insert there

Comment: You should determine it by cursor place and make formation of text, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field, it is not ReactJS task.