# jQuery Set Cursor to Beginning of Input Field on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have an input field `<input value="@website.com" type="text" name="email" id="email">` and I want to make it so when a user focuses on this field, it will move the cursor to be before the `@website.com`.

I have the following Javascript/jQuery code but it does not seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").focusin(function(){
        $("#email").focus();
        $("#email")[0].setSelectionRange(0,0);
    });
});
```

It seems like the `.focus()` keeps calling the `focusin()` function.

I know `$("#email")[0].setSelectionRange(0,0);` is the proper way to move the cursor to the front but how do I bind it to when the field has focus?

Edit: So when I use:

```
$("#email").focus(function(){
    $("#email")[0].setSelectionRange(0,0);
});
```

It sets the cursor to the beginning when I tab into the field but not when I click in.

Edit2: This is different than [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155) because that just gets the caret position whereas I am looking to set the caret position.

Comment: If you and `console.log()` before `$("#email").focus();` above check the console, you will see that you're creating and infinite-loop by doing a `.focus` as the `focusin` event fires, resulting in `maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

Comment: First... `$("#email")[0]` is an abomination. You force jQuery to create an object... Then you use its `[0]`, which is the same as `document.getElementById("#email")`. All more about this element that was added in the jQuery object, you disclose it. -- So that is syntaxically a "doh!"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

Comment: In the above comment of mine, `you disclose it.` should have been read `you discard it.`;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will bind the `focus` AND `click` events of the input field to the function. Hope this helps!

```js
$('#email').on('focus click', function() {
  $(this)[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" autofocus>
<input type="text" id="email" value="@website.com">
```

Or, without jQuery...

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('click', moveCursor);
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('focus', moveCursor);

function moveCursor(event) {
   event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" autofocus>
<input type="text" id="email" value="@website.com">
```

Comment: That works. Well done. You can use `$(this)[0].setSelectionRange(0,0);` instead by the way.

Comment: Ah, true. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need jQuery for this?

```js
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("click", moveCursor);
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("focus", moveCursor);

function moveCursor(event) {
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0,0);
}
```

```html
<input value="@website.com" type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to perform with a cursor needs a field focus anyway.

Here is an old chunk I use. I even named it `cursor.js` in a sub-directory... I took it from many places I guess.

It's a **get/set** cursor position. It takes a JS element. *.oO(`$(el)[0]` for syntax loose..)*

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6


function GetCursorPos (field) {

  // Initialize
  iCaretPos = 0;

  if (isIE){

    // Set focus on the element
    field.focus();

    // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
    oSel = field.createTextRange();

    // Move selection start to 0 position
    oSel.moveStart('character', -field.value.length);

    // The caret position is selection length
    iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
  }

  if (isChrome||isSafari){
    iCaretPos = field.selectionStart;
  }

  if (isFirefox){
    iCaretPos = field.selectionStart;
  }

  return iCaretPos;
}

function SetCursorPos (field,Pos) {

  // Set focus on the element
    field.focus();

  if (isIE){
    field.selectionStart=Pos;
  }

  if (isChrome||isSafari){
    field.setSelectionRange(Pos,Pos);
  }

  if (isFirefox){
    field.selectionStart=Pos;
  }

  return;
}
```

About browser-friendly considerations, there is:

1. [`.selectionStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart) -- Chrome/Safari/Firefox
2. [`.setSelectionRange(Pos,Pos)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) -- Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Internet Explorer
3. [`.createTextRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) -- Internet Explorer

---

An inspiration I used upthere long ago: [partial (compared to the above) SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Updated.