# Getting control where caret was displayed last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an app where it is required to add or delete lines to a `HTML` table.

I programmed the function to add a line to the table in `jQuery`, like:

```
        function othaddrAddLine(evt) {
            var oarow = $("span#othaddrRowToAdd > table > tbody").html();
            $("div#tabs-othaddrs > table#TableOthAddr > tbody").append(oarow);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button#othaddr-add").click(othaddrAddLine);
            $("button#othaddr-del").click(othaddrDelLine);
        });
```

where that `span` contains hidden text.

Now I want to program the `othaddDelLine` function, where I want to delete the line of the table that was in focus.

How can I program this in `jQuery` or `JavaScript`? Is it possible to get the text input control where the caret was, in order to get the parent `<tr>` element and then delete the row.

Thank you.

Comment: What *caret* are you talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field

Comment: *add or delete **lines** to a HTML table* Are you talking about table **rows**? Really, try to be more precise with your terminology.

Comment: One way to do this is by putting the delete button *on the row to be deleted*.  If you have multiple rows with inputs with a single delete button away from the table, it's not clear which row is going to be deleted until the user's deleted a few incorrectly then finally works it out (if they stay long enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

- Add a [focus event listener](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) to all the inputs you have in your table, including the ones you add dynamically.
- Whenever one of those elements is focused, keep a reference to it in a variable. This will be the "last" focused element.
- If the user clicks delete, you can use the reference to that "last" focused input and [get its parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) in order to delete it.

Hope that helps.