# how to find index of text in innerHTML string? Caret position is provided

Tags: javascript, html

I need index of HTML string, I have index of Textual string. How can i find HTML string index that is same as Textual string index?

**HTML string**

```
<div> My name is <span contenteditable="false" id="3" style=" color:rgb(35, 149, 255);">Aaliyah</span>&nbsp; and i am from @.</div>
```

**textual string**

**My name is Aaliyah and i am from @**

caret position is **18**.

Now please tell me, how can i find this 18 caret position index in HTML string? Thanks

**Note:** I need HTML index  of html string. I have caret position of Textual string. They both should point to the same text. weather it is HTML string, or same textual string(with no HTML element).

Comment: Use field.selectionStart example .[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field/48150864#48150864)

Comment: @OleksandrGrin it will only work when type is text area or text. For me its div with contentable property set to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the occurrences of what you are looking for inside the HTML string using a Regular Expression.

```js
let HTMLString = `<div> My name is <span contenteditable="false" id="3" style=" color:rgb(35, 149, 255);">Aaliyah</span>&nbsp; and i am from @.</div>`;

let lookingFor = 'div';
let regex = new RegExp(`${lookingFor}`, 'gi');
let result, indices = [];
while ((result = regex.exec(HTMLString)) ) {
  indices.push(result.index);
}

console.log(indices);
```

Comment: Brother, It will get the text , which i already have, i need index position of HTML string. Because when you are using innerText it removes all the HTML TAGS and elements. I need it with all HTML parameters.

Comment: You need the index of the position of an already existing element? Or you already have the html string? If yes then ````'<div> My name is <span contenteditable="false" id="3" style=" color:rgb(35, 149, 255);">Aaliyah</span>&nbsp; and i am from @.</div>'[18]
```` is the answer.

Comment: Yes, i already have the HTML string, i got it from div.innerHTML. I am using cater position to insert a character, but cater position is of textual string index not of html index.

Comment: I need html string index in number just like cater position of textual string

Comment: You have changed your answer, i see! but what if two tags are identical , it will always return first one, but not second one. so , its not solution i am looking for.

Comment: it will give me all occurrences and i have no way to find, which occurence represent the caret index that i have. 
I need HTML index  of html string. I have caret position of Textual string. They both should point to the same text. weather it is HTML string, or same textual string(with no HTML element).