# How to get current cursor position when editing fabric.Textbox

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How to get current cursor position on text in fabric.Textbox

for example, the following should return = 6

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

Comment: its does logicwise, but i'm more keen on any existing fabricjs solution on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of figured it out. `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` did the trick:

```
var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
var caretPositionStart = activeObj.selectionStart;
var caretPositionEnd = activeObj.selectionEnd;
activeObj.enterEditing();
activeObj.insertChars("HI", null, caretPositionStart, caretPositionEnd);
```